# Make panel visible inside inside gridview control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written like below lines of code

in aspx file

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active">
                  <ItemTemplate>            
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" CssClass="colorlnkbtnedit" runat="server" ToolTip="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "ProductDocument") %>'
                   CommandName="EditIsActive"><i class=" icon-pencil"></i>      </asp:LinkButton>

                  <asp:Panel ID="pnlIsActEdit" runat="server" Visible="false">  
  ...
  ...
         </asp:Panel>

                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

in .cs file

```
    protected void gvProductView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
         ...
         ... 
        }
     else if (e.CommandName == "EditIsActive")
        {
            int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow r = gvProductView.Rows[rowID]; 

            Panel p = (Panel)r.FindControl("pnlIsActEdit");
            p.Visible = false;
        }
     }
```

It's not working !!! It throws `"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"`
 error message at   `GridViewRow r = gvProductView.Rows[rowID];` line of code.

Comment: Use the debugger. What is the value of `rowID` and how many rows does the grid contain? Show also the code where you initialize `e.CommandArgument`.

Comment: I have updated my question... there are 1 row in grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exptect the index of the row  in the `CommandArgument` but actually you are initializing it with the `ProductDocument` of the underyling datasource here:

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductDocument") %>'
```

So   this causes the exception.

Instead use:

```
 CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

or

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why You got this error?

Simply you have 10 rows only, but if your `rowID` is greater than 11. then you got his error.

---

### Solution

Please verify your row count and `rowID` value to solve this issue.

---

### Suggestion

I think you need to get current  selected row. if yes, then please see [this MSDN Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx)